# Transact-SQL programming tools

Tags: sql, eclipse, t-sql, ide, ssms

I am using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio 2008), but I am missing some programming functions that exist in Eclipse for Java, such as:

- Call Hierarchy
- Open Declaration

Are there any tools for SQL Server that offer the same functionality?

Comment: take a look at the Microsoft's `Sql Profiler`

Comment: I am already using it, but can't find these functions on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red Gate has a fairly nice [suite of tools](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-toolbelt/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=sitelinks_sqltoolbelt&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=redgate&gclid=CLGnzIzN660CFYTrKgodMSxR6Q) for working against SQL Server.  Most of the ones that are assistive are plugins to SSMS, which I think you're going to find is common to a lot of SQL Server tool suites.  I haven't used it, but [Toad for Sql Server](http://toadforsqlserver.com/index.jspa) is used by one of the consultants here.

Looking at the two things you've mentioned, you may want to try viewing the execution plan for the query (Query->Include Actual Execution Plan) when executing it against the database  or view dependencies (right click on object->View Dependencies), depending on your scenario.  For most objects you can click and drag them into a query window to see the declaration.